# How to add image storing feature using Firebase Cloud store?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-storage

I am building A notes app with firebase. Where users can login and save notes. I want to add a feature where you can store multiple images and users can check it in different devices just with logging in. Like Google notes. I am pretty sure I should firebase Cloud storage for this but cannot figure out a way to do it. Can someone guide me please

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/start?

Comment: I have already read it before but still cannot understand and want to know how can we fetch multiple images at once from a folder and display it in app @FrankvanPuffelen

Comment: "I didn't understand" is really hard to help with. Without seeing what you tried, it's unlikely we'll explain it better than the product documentation already does. I recommend editing your question to show us what you tried already, so that we have some more context on where you are stuck while implement this use-case.

Answer (score 1):

Register your app with the Firebase, either from the in-built firebase assistant present in Android Studio or from the [firebase website](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup).

For uploading an image, first you have to add the dependency to your app level `build.gradle`

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:$latest-version
```

In the activity, add the following to get the reference of the Firebase storage:

```
 FirebaseStorage.getInstance()
```

Store the reference in an object of type `FirebaseStorage`.
Later wards on can upload image using the reference variable.

You can read the docs
[here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/upload-files)

**Edit**
For uploading multiple images, one can use an Array of URI.

```
ArrayList<Uri> imageListURI
```

Comment: But I want to ask how do I store multiple Images for 1 note and then get all of them at once if the user clicks on the note

Comment: Any thing you can tell for that? @Abhishek Dutt

Comment: Updated @namanop please check if it helps.